# asp.net azure active directory integration error message contains '[PII is hidden]'

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I am getting an error message relating to an attempt to authenticate with azure active directory and in that error message the url it is trying to connect to is shown as '[PII is hidden]'. 
I think i can better resolve the issue if i can see this value but i don't know how to tell .net that it is okay to show it to me. Does anyone know how to force .net to show me the value/url that it is hiding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching i found that the way to make the error and logging show the correct value instead of the text '[PII is hidden]' is to add the following line of code inside your Startup class, ConfigureServices method.

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

after adding this i am now able to see what url is being requested and update my settings accordingly.

Sam

Comment: Well, I got a different error now.  So I guess that's an improvement?