# Azure AD auth - calling web api (multi-tenant) with organizations token fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-web

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that calls an ASP.NET Core web api and I'm using Azure AD with `Microsoft.Identity.Web` . Both have different app registrations in Azure AD and both are configured correctly (Both app registrations now each other, the web app also requests access to the web api, etc..)

This is a multi-tenant application. The web app (front-end) can be used by multiple tenants. Only the web app calls the web-api (back-end), but it also needs to support multiple tenants because we have a database for each tenant.

I feel like I want to use the `organizations` approach and **not** the `common` approach because this application should only be used by other businesses. People with personal accounts should not be able to log in, which is (as far as I know) what `common` is for.

*Funnily enough, when I try to log in using my personal account, I get an error about it not being allowed. Probably because of how I configured my Azure AD app registration?*

### Web app configuration

The web app is configured like this:

```
services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Scopes").Split(" "))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

----
Configuration:

  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ClientId": "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientCertificates": [
      {
        "SourceType": "KeyVault",
        "KeyVaultUrl": "KEYVAULT_URL",
        "KeyVaultCertificateName": "AzureActiveDirectoryAppCert"
      }
    ]
  },

  "Scopes": "https://companyname.com/webapi/Api.Access",
```

When I call my API, I get a token like this and then call the API:

```
var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

// Token is sent successfully to the API
```

### Web api configuration

The web api is configured like this:

```
 services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Audience = "https://companyname.com/webapi;
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false // TODO: Validate that only allowed tenants can access API
        };
    });
```

### The problem

This entire setup works PERFECTLY when I use `common`, but when I use `organizations` I get the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent
```

Some more error details: `{"error":"invalid_tenant","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant 'organizations' not found. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into the correct cloud..."}`

I know that [the common endpoint](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration) has valid openid-configuration whereas the [organizations endpoint](https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/.well-known/openid-configuration) returns a 400, but I don't understand how I am then supposed to make this work.

I tried following an [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-3-AnyOrg) (which uses `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)`) but this also didn't work for the same reasons. Another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60723761/3013479) also looked promising but caused the same error.

How can I add multi-tenant support (whilst still being able to restrict it to specific tenants) in an ASP.NET Core web api that uses an Azure AD App registration?

Comment: No, this is not how the azure active directory multi-tenant  app authentication intended for. If you select `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)` you must choose common instead of specific tenant. Conversely, you can only pass particular tenant Id if you select single tenant configuration while registered your app on azure portal. You can [`get more details here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview)

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, thank you for your reply. So in what context would one call `organizations` instead of `common`?

Comment: If you need to authenticate with single or particular tenant you should stict to `Accounts in this organizational directory only (Microsoft only - Single tenant)`  means All user and guest accounts in designated directory can use your application or API but choosing multi-tenant then sending tenant Id instead of common wound ended with with additional issue and might not work properly and this is how it designed for.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, this doesn't really answer my question. I have chosen `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)` so multiple companies can use this application. However, my API will only allow authorized tenants. Online I read that `common` is also for personal accounts, which conflicts with the supported account type above. So: Why is `common` good enough, and why should I not want to use `organizations`?

Comment: Yes you are right prsonal account can be used and its good because for multi tenant its a convension to use common instead of particular ID through request URL.

Answer (score 1):

When I used the organizations endpoint , I was getting the same error.

appsetting.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "testthetenant365.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "50xxxx06e",
    "TenantId": "Organizations",
    "ClientSecret": "ZHxxxbGh",
    //Audience": "50xxx06e",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    /*
     'Scopes' contains space separated scopes of the Web API you want to call. This can be:
      - a scope for a V2 application (for instance api:xx/access_as_user)
      - a scope corresponding to a V1 application (for instance <App ID URI>/.default, where  <App ID URI> is the
        App ID URI of a legacy v1 Web application
        App ID URI of a legacy v1 Web application
      Applications are registered in the https:portal.azure.com portal.
    */
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    //"Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"
    //"Scopes": "api://xxxx/access_as_user"
     "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

  },
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Organizations/xxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Organizations/xxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
```

[image]

> **Note:** /common endpoints supports personal accounts but /organizatioms support only work or school accounts.

Then I checked and changed the  support account type of my registered application:

[image]

Then it asked for admin consent to access the endpoint.
Note: The account with which I logged in was work and school account

[image]

I have `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2`, in the manifest of my App registration.

Make sure the tenant with user is going to login is allowed by the application and granted admin consent to api permissions.z

And check on  the audience  part [Client application configuration (MSAL) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#how-to-specify-the-audience-in-your-codeconfiguration)

With permissions granted and with above configuration, the endpoint worked:

[image]

And scope is for graph as I am calling grapph endpoint  with `/.default` .
scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.`

For your api : check scope if it has to be granted for other permissions `api://<clientId>/.default.`

[image]

Alternatively , if you know the tenant Id’s of tenants to be allowed , they can be validated.
Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuers = new[] { "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID1/v2.0", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID2/v2.0" },
            //token validation parameters...
        };
    });
```

See [Convert single-tenant app to multi-tenant on Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

Comment: Hi @kavyas . Thank you for your reply. A few questions: 

- You show an error about "Organizations/xxx/ not being known. This is different than my error (without the id). What is our difference in code?
- In your final bit of the comment I see the AddJwtBearer() bit with the common endpoint. However, I'm looking for organizations. Is that a typo on your end?
- In the beginning of your comment you have some AzureAd json, is that for the web app or web api? 
- Why is the accessTokenAcceptedVersion important? my web api's version is null and it works for me

Comment: That error occurred to me According to my App settings.  Alternate way which was given without using organizations to mention selected tenants with common endpoints if no way is working out(If it's the case ). I've mentioned accessTokenAcceptedVersion 2,  as the endpoint may vary depending on the version.